# Output an Array or List to String

Tags: arrays, string, list, vba

I wrote the following piece of code (in VBA in outlook) to try to output my list to a string. This way may not be perfect; it compiles, but I have not tested it yet; in any case, I'm wondering if any of you have any alternative ideas about how to go about outputting an array or a list to a string, either in VBA or VB.NET. This way just feels kind of jury-rigged to me, and I was not able to find any kind of 'standard' or 'official' way to get this done.

It is not essential that I have an alternative as I think this code will work, but I am very new to this and I would like to learn as much as possible from this project. So thanks for any help you could offer!

```
    Dim nplct As Integer
    Dim npl As Integer
    Dim strNotpresentList As String
    strNotpresentList = ""
    npl = 0
    nplct = notpresentList.Count
    For Each Computer In notpresentList
        If npl <> nplct Then

            If strNotpresentList = "" Then
                    strNotpresentList = notpresentList(npl)
                    npl = npl + 1
                Else
                    strNotpresentList = strNotpresentList & ", " & notpresentList(np1)
                    npl = npl + 1
                End If


            Else
                strNotpresentList = strNotpresentList & ", " & notpresentList(np1) & "."
            End If

    Next Computer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's for VBA:**

```
Dim strNotPresentList as String
strNotPresentList = Join(notpresentList, ",") & "."
```

Or if you want it on the same line:

```
Dim strNotPresentList As String: strNotPresentList = Join(notpresentList, ",") & "."
```

**For VB.Net**

```
Dim strNotPresentList As String = String.Join(", ", notpresentList) + "."
```

Comment: Thanks! So, what exactly does this replace? Can I replace `strNotpresentList = strNotpresentList & ", " & notpresentList(np1) & "."` with `strNotPresentList = Join(notpresentList, ",") & "."` ?

Comment: It can replace all of the code that you pasted if you add a Dim to the beginning.

Comment: @TimB Wow. That's unexpected. Thank you!

Comment: This will not work in VBA (code will not compile), but it will work in VB.Net. I'm updating my examples to show how to define as String and assign as briefly as possible for both.

Answer (score 2):

In VB.NET:

```
strNotpresentList = String.Join(", ", notpresentList)
```